# File formats for Stars! by Mare Crisium

Tags: encryption, file-format, fileparsing, dosbox

There is an old strategy came called Stars! by Mare Crisium.

I would like to write some AI to play this game, but I don't get much fun out of trying to decipher file formats.

Does anyone know the format of the X and H files that are used for turns?  Or at the very least have some guidance on how they would start trying to decipher them?    I am currently using GIT to save history then watching what changes after different actions, but it is very slow going.

http://www.starsfaq.com/index.htm

There are some links in there to download the game, make donations, or find keys to play.

Comment: You may get lucky, but somehow, I doubt it. The FAQ page you link to mentions an open source clone; have you looked at that?  They will presumably have reverse engineered the file formats.

Comment: Contact the creators of the game http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Crisium_Studios, chances are they will help you.

Comment: I am guessing they are using PGP.  My next step is to extract all of the readable strings try using them as keys.  Failing that letting a brute force method run against it a few days.  I hope "the Jeffs" as game fans call them see fit to release the keys and save me some hours.

Comment: Well PGP failed pretty quickly... What other encryption may have been used at that time?